# how to add flag array to images?

Tags: c#

I have 9 images set up in a grid. How do I randomise which image goes into the grid. For example how to stop image 1 always going into grid 1

```
GridPic1.Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic1.jpeg"));
GridPic2.Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic2.jpeg"));
GridPic3.Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic3.jpeg"));
GridPic4.Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic4.jpeg"));
GridPic5.Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic5.jpeg"));
GridPic6.Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic6.jpeg"));
GridPic7.Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic7.jpeg"));
GridPic8.Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic8.jpeg"));
GridPic9.Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic9.jpeg"));
```

Apparently a flag array can be added into each of these, but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: Add the images to a list, shuffle the list, assign an image to each GridPic like `GridPic1.Source = shuffledImages[0]; GridPic2.Source = shuffledImages[1];`, etc.

Comment: P.S. My comment comes from not knowing what you're dealing with here, or what a "flag array" is in this context (I'd think an array of true/false values, but presumably not?). Hopefully it's helpful anyway.

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly do you mean by a flag array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign your bitmapimages to a list, randomize them, and assign them to the sources:

```cs
/*initialize our bitmapimages in a list*/
List<BitmapImage> randomList = new List<BitmapImage>();
randomList.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic1.jpeg")));
randomList.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic1.jpeg")));
randomList.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic2.jpeg")));
randomList.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic3.jpeg")));
randomList.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic4.jpeg")));
randomList.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic5.jpeg")));
randomList.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic6.jpeg")));
randomList.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic7.jpeg")));
randomList.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pic1/Pic8.jpeg")));

/*random shuffle our list*/
Random r = new Random();
randomList = randomList.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).ToList();

/*assign random order to the gridpic*/
GridPic1.Source = randomList[0];
GridPic2.Source = randomList[1];
GridPic3.Source = randomList[2];
GridPic4.Source = randomList[3];
GridPic5.Source = randomList[4];
GridPic6.Source = randomList[5];
GridPic7.Source = randomList[6];
GridPic8.Source = randomList[7];
GridPic9.Source = randomList[8];
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Linq` for this to work.